# Multiple tables JOIN with WHERE clause including rows that haven't common id

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I suppose this topic has been discussed already here. However I couldn't find something useful for my issue, so links are welcomed.

There are three tables. Table `test2` have two foreign keys for tables `test1` and `test3`.

```
    test1                          test2                               test3
+----+------+           +----+-------+-------+----+             +----+------------+
| id | name |           | id | t1_id | t3_id | v2 |             | id |   co_date  |
+----+------+           +----+-------+-------+----+             +----+------------+
|  1 |   A  |           | 1  |   3   |   1   | 15 |             |  1 | 2018-12-02 |
|  2 |   B  |           | 2  |   4   |   1   | 20 |             |  2 | 2019-02-03 |
|  3 |   C  |           | 3  |   9   |   2   | 35 |             |  3 | 2019-03-04 |
|  4 |   D  |           | 4  |   5   |   3   | 12 |             |  4 | 2019-04-05 |
|  5 |   E  |           | 5  |   6   |   3   | 12 |             |  5 | 2019-09-01 |
|  6 |   F  |           | 6  |   9   |   4   | 20 |             |  6 | 2019-10-02 |
|  7 |   G  |           | 7  |   6   |   5   | 10 |             |  7 | 2019-11-03 |
|  8 |   H  |           | 8  |   7   |   5   | 10 |             |  8 | 2019-12-04 |
|  9 |   I  |           | ....................... |             |  9 | 2020-02-05 |
| 10 |   J  |           | 20 |   4   |  10   | 30 |             | 10 | 2020-03-06 |
+----+------+           +----+-------+-------+----+             +----+------------+
```

I want to sum all v2 values from `test2` by names within certain period. The problem is that some names are not presented in that period. And they are excluded from query result.

I've tried to use LEFT-hand join, but it doesn't work that way.

```sql
SELECT t1.name, SUM(v2) FROM test1 as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 as t2 
  ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN test3 as t3 
  ON t2.t3_id = t3.id
WHERE co_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

The following result doesn't include `'A'` to `'D'` names.

```
+------+---------+
| name | SUM(v2) |
+------+---------+
|   E  |    26   |
|   F  |    37   |
|   G  |    35   |
|   H  |    10   |
|   I  |    90   |
|   J  |    20   |
+------+---------+
```

But I expected that they should be with `NULL` in other fields. Isn't this the way how `LEFT JOIN` works: all rows from left table and intersections with other tables?

Also, I have tried Cartesian product, but I don't know how to group it correctly.

[Here's the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a07e80f91a56637c9c0be916ba8bacc9).
I will appreciate any advice about how should I think here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the date filters in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT t1.name, SUM(v2)
FROM test1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     test2 t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.t1_id LEFT JOIN
     test3 t3 
     ON t2.t3_id = t3.id AND
        t3.co_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.name
ORDER BY name;
```

The `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join -- which is why you lose rows.  It does so because `NULL` fails the comparison in the `WHERE` clause filtering the "outer joined" results.

Comment: Why the one doesn't tell about it in various JOIN types descriptions?.. Thank you, Gordon.

Comment: @Gennadiy: They don't do so explicitly, but they mention that the outer joined columns are null, so `WHERE t3.co_date BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND DATE '2019-12-31'` must necessarily dismiss these rows.